# Get response when every jQuery Ajax requests is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can get response when 'all' Ajax requests are done from this question.

[Wait until all jQuery Ajax requests are done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done)

While I can't find a question to get 'every' response when each Ajax are done.

How can I do this?

Example for wait until all responses done, but I want to get response when each ajax complete.

```
function translate(...){
    return $.ajax({
        // settings...
    });
});

var requests = [];
translatable_fields.each(function(){
    requests.push(translate(...));
});

$.when.apply($, requests).done(function(schemas) {
     console.log("All requests complete");
    // do something...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The responses will be passed to the callback for `done`. Each AJAX call will get its own parameter, and each parameter will be an array of the three parts of the response: the response text, the status, and the jqXHR object associated with the AJAX call. [Documentation for `$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

You can get the response texts all at once using the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

```
$.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
    var responses = $.map(arguments, function(arr) { return arr[0] });
});
```